# I want to set entity values based on condition. How to do that in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am making a bot for booking rooms. For booking rooms a user can choose "Premium Service" or "Standard Service".

However the hotels available to be booked depends on "Premium" or "Standard".

How to do this in dialog flow?

I tried to set entities "Service_type" and "Hotels". However how to set values for entity "Hotels" based on "Service_type" the user has selected?

Please note that the intent of the bot is book rooms. And there are many other steps to be followed to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating an entity like `quality` and it's helpful to think of other ways that the user might refer to the quality that you define as "standard" and "premium"

[image]

Now when you create your intents you should see that Dialogflow automatically detects your entity in the training phrases

[image]

If Dialogflow doesn't already detect your entity, you can highlight a word in the training phrase and associate it to a type of your choosing

[image]

That's the easy part.

In order to present a different set of hotels depending on which standard that was selected, you should look into developing a [fulfillment endpoint](https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/integrate-services-actions-on-google) that handles the logic.

The quality choice that the user made in the first question will be passed as a parameter and you can easily make conditional logic to select hotels depending on that

```
conv.ask(`Here is a list of ${quality} hotel options for you`);
if (quality === "premium") {
    conv.ask(getPremiumHotelOptions()); // Carousel or list
} else {
    conv.ask(getStandardHotelOptions()); // Carousel or list
}
```

Comment: hey I feel the best way is to use context. Because doing the above way you cant verify user inputs for premium and standard.

Comment: You must first pass them to a followup intent via parameter values if you are parsing them out of user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty `Hotels` entity and then [populate it with the relevant entity values for that session](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes) in your fulfillment webhook.

If you're using node.js for your webhook, you can look into the [Dialogflow library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow) to do much of this work. The call might look something like this:

```
  const sessionEntityTypeRequest = {
    parent: sessionPath,
    sessionEntityType: {
      name: sessionEntityTypePath,
      entityOverrideMode: entityOverrideMode,
      entities: entities,
    },
  };

  const [response] = await sessionEntityTypesClient.createSessionEntityType(
    sessionEntityTypeRequest
  );
```

(See a more complete example at https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/resource.js in the `createSessionEntityType()` function)